# Insert into table, selecting ID from secondary table

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I have 2 tables:
tblSupplier (unique suppliers)
Columns = ID, SupplierName

tblFruit
Columns = ID, SupplierID, Price

I have the supplier name and the prices, and I want to insert rows into tblFruit. But how do I insert the ID (rather than the SupplierName)?

I can extract the ID I want to insert with a second query like this: Select ID from tblSupplier where SupplierName = [ParamSupplierName]...but it must be possible in one query...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: *"I have the supplier name and the prices"*  Where do you have those values?  In a third table?

Comment: They are in Excel. I export to the access database row by row.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tblFruit (SupplierID,Price)
SELECT ID, Price
FROM tlSupplier
WHERE SupplierName = @ParamSupplierName
```